# how do you run predict on time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, predict

I am trying to create prediction based on time series data.

My data frame call dat looks like this:

dput(head(dat))

```
dat <- structure(list(out = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Date = c(1423825200000, 
1423825500000, 1423825800000, 1423826100000, 1423826400000, 1423826700000
)), .Names = c("out", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Currently there are 81 rows in my data frame dat. My columns are called out and Date, Date column is in epoch.

I need to build a linear model first:

```
 lin <- lm(dat[,1]~dat[,2], data=dat)
```

based on this model, I need to predict hourly data points for 7 days etc so, I do this:

```
t<-3600
newdata <- seq(tail(dat$Date,1), tail(dat$Date,1)+604800, t)
newdata<-data.frame(newdata)
    colnames(newdata)<-c("Date")
    predictions <- predict(lin, newdata=newdata, level=0.95, interval="prediction")
    predictions <- data.frame(predictions)
    f<-predictions
    f<-data.frame(f)
    f<-cbind(f, newdata)
    f<-f[,c("fit", "Date")]
    colnames(f)<-c("Forecast", "Date")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 81, 169 In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 169 rows but variables found have 81 rows
```

Regardless of the size of my data frame (dat), I should be able to build a linear model and based on newdata, I should execute the predict function. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Maybe some of your variables are factors that are expanded in `lm`

Comment: @kristang, they are numeric.

Comment: try using the names of the variables in the formula `lin <- lm(out~Date, data=dat)`

Comment: @NicE, it worked, but should it matter. I want to be able to do this via a function within an R package where I need everything to be dynamic. I am afraid, issuing lm function on names may intoduce some other problems etc.

Comment: @user1471980 I might be able to help you. Please tell me the dim of your training and dim of your test set. Please tell me whether you are building a OLS (only one variable against one variable) ? or doing something else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. In this way, you can still keep everything dynamic.

```
variable.list<-names(dat)
lin <- lm(as.formula(paste(variable.list[1],variable.list[2], sep="~") ), data=dat)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: What's happening here is that, in your original code, the two variables you used in your linear model is called dat[,1] and dat[,2], instead of "out" and "Date". You can check the names by `names(lin$coefficients)` As a result, the predict was not able to correlate the linear model with your new dataset in the correct way.